# jQuery : Progress bar flickers during scroll, when scrollHeight is used to get the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scroll box where list items gets added dynamically. I have placed progress bar on top of it, to keep track of height of the scroll box. I have used `scrollHeight` to get the current height of the scroll box.

The problem I am facing here is that the progress bar flickers when the scroll box is scrolled. It also prevents the box from scrolling. However, I get the correct height of the scrollbox. if I replace a random number instead of getting height from `scrollHeight`, the progress bar shows smooth transitions.

What's the issue with the code? Thanks !

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class = "outer-box">
  <progress class = "progress_bar" id = "progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <div class="scrollBox">
      <div class = "scroll_text">
        <ul>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
          <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
$(".scrollBox").scroll(function () {
  var s = $(".scrollBox").scrollTop(),
    d = $(".scrollBox").scrollTop($(".scrollBox"))[0].scrollHeight,
    c = $(".scrollBox").height(),
    scrollPercent = (s / (d-c)) * 100;
    var position = scrollPercent;
    $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);
});
```

*Here's the working demo* : [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/yqexftcs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In third line you are setting new value for `scrollTop` of `.scrollBox` that is why scroll bar is flickering every time user scrolls element. Here is corrected version:

```js
$(".scrollBox").scroll(function () {
  var s = $(".scrollBox").scrollTop(),
      d = $(".scrollBox")[0].scrollHeight, // Just get scrollHeight
      c = $(".scrollBox").height(),
      scrollPercent = (s / (d-c)) * 100;
  var position = scrollPercent;
  $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);
});
```

```css
.outer-box{
    margin-top: 11.6%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 76.3%;
}
.scrollBox {
    margin-top: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 76.3%;
    height: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5px 0.5px #ABABAB inset, 0 0 6px #ABABAB;
    outline: 0 none ;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    z-index: -10;
}
.scroll_text{
    margin: 3%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
.chat_item {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    margin-left: -2%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    max-width: 90%;
    float: left;
    /*box-shadow: 0 3.5px 0.5px #428bca inset, 0 0 0px grey;*/
}
.chat_text{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
progress {
 position:fixed;
 width: 79.5%;
 height: 8px;
    top:36px;
 z-index: 100;
    margin-left: -0.08%;
    margin-top: 5.6%;
 background-color: blue;

}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {background:#54cfca}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {background:#54cfca}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {background:#54cfca}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "outer-box">
  <progress class = "progress_bar" id = "progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <div class="scrollBox">
    <div class = "scroll_text">
      <ul>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
        <li class = "chat_item" id = "sample"> <p class = "chat_text"> Hey there ! I am blah blah blah..cool'</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks ! Btw, how is it getting set ? The syntax says, `.scrollTop( value )` - A number indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to. This however isn't `d = $(".scrollBox").scrollTop($(".scrollBox")[0].scrollHeight)`. The parenthesis are different.

Comment: @build_code Actually its the same. If we divide this line into two, we'll get next: `var scrollTop = $(".scrollBox")[0].scrollHeight`, and after that we pass this value to `scrollTop` - `$(".scrollBox").scrollTop(scrollTop)`

Comment: It's the same ? Interesting.. Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue, and the jQuery was correct but it still caused an annoying flicker. After several attempts I narrowed it down to the fact that I had an empty line in the text box (I was scrolling to bottom of text box and then updating progressbar underneath). The empty line caused the scroll calculations to go wrong. Once the empty line was removed then everything was working and the progress bar was not longer flickering......  so the moral of this story: beware of empty lines in textboxes (i.e. lines with just CRLF)... better to remove them.